# Circle/Rectangle Shapes Drawing using ArcGIS Java SDK

Tags: javafx, drawing, desktop-application, arcgis-runtime

so i've been working on a map related desktop application (in JavaFX) using ArcGIS Java SDK 100.6.0. I want to draw certain shapes on the map and save them. I've seen the documentation and as far as i know they provide a `SketchEditor` class for drawing on map. The class object allows me to draw freehand, polylines and polygons on the map. My application requires a complete drawing feature to draw various shapes. This class does not allow me to draw squares, rectanlges, circles. My question is that how can i draw these shapes on my mapview. Has anyone ever come up with any idea to draw shapes apart from the `SketchEditor`'s available ones.

Edit: I think my question is not clear enough. I'll just share what my application requires and what i can actually implement:

[These are are the shapes that i want my application to support](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DoxlP.png)

[These are the shapes that ArcGIS Java SDK currently supports](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGlvA.png)

Now I've found a workaround for circle from this link:

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26636/draw-a-circle-in-arcgis-map

Now the shapes that remain are rectangle/square. I hope someone can share how they solved this problem in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to find workarounds for the drawing of those unsupported shapes. It was found that by using the polygon geometry, and by giving the right points, i can create those shapes (Circle, Square, Rectangle). Here is the code snippet that shows how i managed to draw those shapes (The methods that return graphic object for the shapes):

**Circle**

```
public static Graphic drawFullCircle(Point centerPoint, double radius, int borderColor) {
    int ptCount = 240;
    double slice = 2 * Math.PI / ptCount;
    PointCollection pc = new PointCollection(SpatialReferences.getWgs84());
    for (int i = 0; i <= ptCount; i++) {
        double rad = slice * i;
        double px = centerPoint.getX() + radius * Math.cos(rad);
        double py = centerPoint.getY() + radius * Math.sin(rad);
        pc.add(new Point(px, py));
    }
    Polygon poly = new Polygon(new PartCollection(pc));
    SimpleFillSymbol sfs = new SimpleFillSymbol(SimpleFillSymbol.Style.SOLID, 0x00FFFFFF, new SimpleLineSymbol(SimpleLineSymbol.Style.SOLID, borderColor, 1.5f));
    Graphic g = new Graphic(poly, sfs);
    return g;
}
```

I was able to draw rectangular shapes using the `Envelop` geometry.

**Rectangle**

```
public static Graphic drawRectangle(Point p1, Point p2, int borderColor) {
    Envelope envelope = new Envelope(p1, p2); // start (p1) and end (p2) points of a diagonal
    PointCollection pc = new PointCollection(SpatialReferences.getWgs84());
    pc.add(new Point(envelope.getXMin(), envelope.getYMin()));
    pc.add(new Point(envelope.getXMax(), envelope.getYMin()));
    pc.add(new Point(envelope.getXMax(), envelope.getYMax()));
    pc.add(new Point(envelope.getXMin(), envelope.getYMax()));

    Polygon poly = new Polygon(new PartCollection(pc));
    SimpleFillSymbol sfs = new SimpleFillSymbol(SimpleFillSymbol.Style.SOLID, 0x00FFFFFF, new SimpleLineSymbol(SimpleLineSymbol.Style.SOLID, borderColor, 1.5f));
    return new Graphic(poly, sfs);
}
```

**Square**

```
public static Graphic drawSquare(Point p1, Point p2, int borderColor) {
    Envelope rectEnvelope = new Envelope(p1, p2); start (p1) and end (p2) points of a diagonal

    PointCollection pc = new PointCollection(SpatialReferences.getWgs84());
    // these conditions make sure that the square is created from the start point and not from any other point.
    if(rectEnvelope.getWidth() > rectEnvelope.getHeight())
    {
        if(p2.getX() > p1.getX())
        {
            pc.add(new Point(rectEnvelope.getXMin(), rectEnvelope.getYMin()));
            pc.add(new Point(rectEnvelope.getXMin()+rectEnvelope.getHeight(), rectEnvelope.getYMin()));
            pc.add(new Point(rectEnvelope.getXMin()+rectEnvelope.getHeight(), rectEnvelope.getYMax()));
            pc.add(new Point(rectEnvelope.getXMin(), rectEnvelope.getYMax()));
        }
        else
        {
            pc.add(new Point(rectEnvelope.getXMax()-rectEnvelope.getHeight(), rectEnvelope.getYMax()-rectEnvelope.getHeight()));
            pc.add(new Point(rectEnvelope.getXMax(), rectEnvelope.getYMin()));
            pc.add(new Point(rectEnvelope.getXMax(), rectEnvelope.getYMax()));
            pc.add(new Point(rectEnvelope.getXMax()-rectEnvelope.getHeight(), rectEnvelope.getYMax()));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(p2.getY() > p1.getY())
        {
            pc.add(new Point(rectEnvelope.getXMin(), rectEnvelope.getYMin()));
            pc.add(new Point(rectEnvelope.getXMax(), rectEnvelope.getYMin()));
            pc.add(new Point(rectEnvelope.getXMax(), rectEnvelope.getYMin()+rectEnvelope.getWidth()));
            pc.add(new Point(rectEnvelope.getXMin(), rectEnvelope.getYMin()+rectEnvelope.getWidth()));
        }
        else
        {
            pc.add(new Point(rectEnvelope.getXMin(), rectEnvelope.getYMax()-rectEnvelope.getWidth()));
            pc.add(new Point(rectEnvelope.getXMax(), rectEnvelope.getYMax()-rectEnvelope.getWidth()));
            pc.add(new Point(rectEnvelope.getXMax(), rectEnvelope.getYMax()));
            pc.add(new Point(rectEnvelope.getXMin(), rectEnvelope.getYMax()));
        }
    }

    Polygon poly = new Polygon(new PartCollection(pc));
    SimpleFillSymbol sfs = new SimpleFillSymbol(SimpleFillSymbol.Style.SOLID, 0x00FFFFFF, new SimpleLineSymbol(SimpleLineSymbol.Style.SOLID, borderColor, 1.5f));
    return new Graphic(poly, sfs);
}
```

This might contain unoptimized code logic however this is all what we have for now with ArcGIS Java SDK 100.6.0. Any edits and suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to create graphic overlays.  Squares, rectangles, circles = polygons. However, you could create the option to add square or circle marker symbols as points and then allow the user to scale the symbols to make them larger or smaller.

https://developers.arcgis.com/labs/net/display-point-line-and-polygon-graphics/
https://developers.arcgis.com/java/10-2/guide/add-graphics-and-text-to-graphic-overlays.htm

Comment: That is one approach i can take. however, i'm not sure if i can use MarkerSymbols as shapes and if i can color the shape inside and it's outline differently. Appreciate your answer though.